# Set value of 2 keys at same calling on a table

Tags: lua

What am I looking for is a code like that.

```
local sometable = {
    [1] = [2] = "abc",
}
```

So this is surely a wrong way to set 2 keys. ( returned an error )

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You received an error because Lua doesn't have a syntax for setting multiple keys to a single value in a table constructor.

You have a few options, when using tables as arrays (sequences) you can omit the key:

```
local t = {'abc', 'abc'}
```

If you don't want to repeat the value, use a variable:

```
local init = 'abc'
local t = {init, init}
```

Or, write a function to do the initialization:

```
local function initialize(t, v, first, last)
    first = first or 1
    last = last or first
    assert(first <= last, 'invalid first/last')
    for i = first, last do
        t[i] = v
    end
    return t
end

local t = initialize({}, 'abc', 1, 2)
```

Comment: `initialize` function is very neat solution.